# Trigger click on anchor when div is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class="test">
    <span>some text</span>
    <a href="www.test.com">click here</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <span>some text</span>
    <a href="www.test.com">click here</a>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <span>some text</span>
    <a href="www.test.com">click here</a>
</div>
```

When the the page loads, using jQuery, I want to apply a click event to every div on the page with the class "test". So when you click on the div, the anchor link within that div is triggered.
How is this done?
I've tried the following code, but get the error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

```
$( ".test" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( this ).find("a").trigger("click");
});
```

I've also tried the first answer below, which works fine, however, it doesn't handle different link targets like _blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the click event works for links. However, you can always set the window location.

```
$( ".test" ).on( "click", function() {
    window.open( $( this ).find("a").attr('href') );
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, but how do you handle to target for the link? Eg, "_blank"

Comment: Looks like you can use `window.open` instead. I've updated my answer.